# File not shown in git diff after a git add. How do I know it will be committed?

Tags: git, file, commit, git-commit, git-diff

I had an untracked file which was not appearing in a git diff and when I added it to the 'changes to be committed' area, it still doesn't show up in the git diff. I shows up with a `git status -v` when I do a diff against HEAD.

I'm still very new to git, so could anyone please tell me if the file will be committed even if it doesn't show up in a regular diff, as it has been added to the staging area?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you'd like to see the *staged* changes in a diff, you can still use `git diff`, you just need to pass the `--staged` flag:

```sh
david@pav:~/dummy_repo$ echo "Hello, world" > hello.txt
david@pav:~/dummy_repo$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   hello.txt
nothing added to commit but untracked files present
david@pav:~/dummy_repo$ git add hello.txt
david@pav:~/dummy_repo$ git diff
david@pav:~/dummy_repo$ git diff --staged
diff --git a/hello.txt b/hello.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..76d5293
--- /dev/null
+++ b/hello.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+Hello, world
```

If you only care about which files are staged, you can of course do a `git status`, but `git diff --staged --name-only` will give each staged filename on its own line.

Comment: If, in the mean time, you create changes to the staged files, those changes will show in `git diff` and `git diff --staged` will only show the staged files at the point at which they were staged.

Answer (score 38):

To see all the changes in the working tree since your last commit including new files use:

```
git diff HEAD
```

See more examples here: [git-diff](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Answer (score 5):

As you've seen. it shows in `git status`, so yes it will be committed when you `git commit` it.

You may find it helpful to use a visual git tool such as gitx (Mac) or gitg (Linux),

It has nice panels to show you staged, not staged, etc.

[image]

My screenshot seems spare as I currently have no changes in that status.

Answer (score 1):

If you typed in "git add __", the file will be included in your next commit. This commit will be pushed to the server when you run "git push".

Comment: What good is this answer? How about if you want to just take a manual patch for some reason. (dont bother replying with why would you want to? there are hundreds of reasons why i'd want to)

Comment: @Stephen, this is an answer I wrote 2 years ago, and so I'm taking a guess as to what my thought process was back then. The OP's post ends with the question "Could anyone please tell me if the file will be committed even if it doesn't show up in a regular diff, as it has been added to the staging area?". This is a direct answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add to David Cain's top answer the following nuance: the command...

```
git diff --staged
```

...shows only the staged changes (as @rogerdpack pointed out).

Now, If you're only after generating the diff of a single file then I have nothing to add. But if what you're after is to generate a diff file with "*all changes since the latest HEAD*", then you probably should (1.) stage all files with changes, (2.) run the diff, (3.) unstage all files, as follows:

```
git add -A
git diff --staged HEAD
git reset
```

Needless to say, bear in mind that these commands will mess around with **all** your previously staged and unstaged files, so you should exercise caution if you have lots of temporary files lying around. See the [git diff's](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) manual page for more info.